# Rows getting automatically deleted in Oracle database table

Tags: sql, database, oracle, database-administration

Rows for certain column value is automatically deleted within 30 sec from an Oracle database table. I have searched all schedular, procedures, and all_source nowhere I could find any delete or truncate statement against table.

There are other records as well in table but only records against certain column value are getting deleted.

Comment: How do you know that they are *automatically* deleted? I mean, maybe someone (a human) deleted them.

Comment: it gets deleted within 30 sec...and not many have access to database

Comment: Audit should and will help here!

Comment: Do you make commit after your transaction?

Comment: Apply a trigger on before delete and log the culprit process in any other table.

Comment: Do you have access to a DBA team or do you have DBA privileges yourself?